# No signature match between same type across different modules

Tags: julia

I have the following (simplified) module structure in my program.

[image]

I have also detailed the simplified structure of each module.

```
module Entities
    export Agent, Space
    struct Agent
        .
    end
    struct Space
        .
    end
end
```

```
module Loader
    export load_data, read_config
    include("./entities.jl")
    using .Entities: Agent, Space

    function read_config(...)
        .
    end
    function load_data(...)::Tuple{Vector{Space}, Vector{Agent}}
        .
    end
end
```

```
module Scheduler
    include("./loader.jl")
    include("./entities.jl")
    using .Loader: load_data, read_config
    using .Entities: Agent, Space

    function main()
        spaces, agents = load_data(read_config("scenarios/eq_2.json"))
        synthetise_schedule(agents, spaces, order)
        # println(typeof(spaces), "\t", typeof(agents), "\t", typeof(locations), "\t", typeof(order))
    end
    function synthetise_schedule(agents::Vector{Agent}, spaces::Vector{Space})
        .
    end
    main()
end
```

Now, when I run the `scheduler.jl` file, I get the following error

```
LoadError: MethodError: no method matching synthetise_schedule(::Array{Main.Scheduler.Loader.Entities.Agent,1}, ::Array{Main.Scheduler.Loader.Entities.Space,1})
```

It looks like the REPL treat `Main.Scheduler.Loader.Entities.*` and `Main.Scheduler.Entities.*` as different types, although they eventually all refer to the same original types `Entities.*`.

**Now, I am not sure if this behavior comes from the fact that I am missing a set of instructions within each module or if it is the expected behavior in Julia.**

In any case, how can I make sure that my `synthetise_schedule` function accepts `Main.Scheduler.Loader.Entities.*` types as input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `include("./entities.jl")` in your code twice. Note that `include` is like copy-paste of the contents of the file. So essentially you define twice the same thing in different modules. Although the definitions are the same (it terms of code) they are separate (think of it as if you copy-pasted the same code twice in two different name spaces).

You should `include("./entities.jl")` only once and then refer to to the namespace where you made this `include` in both other parts of your code.